# Alternative of stopping service in onDestroy() of Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding, otto

I am starting android service by `startService()` in  Activity A. I have multiple activities in my application. Here the problem is with `onDestroy()` of Activities.

What I am doing is generating an event in `onDestroy()` of activity. Application class is a subscriber of this event and I stopping this service in Application class. I know `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called every time when the application is closing.

**I also need to keep service running till application is running.** 
**And what is the best way to stopping service on the closing of application?**

I am using **otto** library for event bus.

Comment: Try startService in onResume() and stopService() in onPause() instead?

Comment: But it will stop service onPause of one activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background/5862048#5862048  , this will provide direction , using application class

Comment: Okay then you may try put it in onStop(). See Activity lifecycle in http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: do not start the `Service` then (startService) but rather bind to it (bindService)

Comment: @pskink if I use bindService, unbindService in onResume() and onPause(). then service will be stopped when on client is bound to it.

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html#Additional_Notes

Comment: Thank you @pskink. You are at the right point. Here I tried same. I tried to bind an activity to service in onCreate() and unbind it in onDestroy(). But problem is that in Android it's not guaranteed that onDestroy() will be called on the closing of application. So there are situations when onDestory() isn't called and Service keeps running.

Comment: no, there is no such case, first of all find the following in the link i posted *'''When your client is destroyed, it will unbind from the service, but you should always unbind when you're done interacting with the service or when your activity pauses so that the service can shutdown while its not being used.'''*, secondly `Activity#onDestroy` is not called only when the whole process is killed, so the `Service` is killed too

Answer (score 0):

You can start `Service` in `HeadlessFragment` and add this `HeadlessFragment` in you `activity`

Example for implementing and understanding headless fragment http://luboganev.github.io/blog/headless-fragments/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) in your `Application` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize anything application wide

        // this is important, otherwise it won't work
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        // your application is running, do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        // your application was closed, stop any service or something else.
    }
}
```

This is the best way to keep track of the lifecycle of the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) or [TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) depending on your requirements to detect Activtys' visibility.